# Node.js/Socket.io How do I stop simple value changing from the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am creating a game where I keep a few variables such as fallingSpeed, runningSpeed etc. Right now my solution to stop the simple console editing in browser by using setTimeout(...){someFunction(...)}; to send the correct data to the client.

So what happens is that, when a player connects the speed of 1 is sent to the client. After that the server waits for a request which is sent to the it when 'space' has either been pressed or released. However, this causes problem since setTimeout(...){...} only runs once. So the client can just press 'space' once and while in the air, open the console and simply type fallingSpeed = 0; and start hovering around the map.

```
// use socket.io
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var speedTimer;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('fallingSpeed', {'fallingSpeed': 1});

    // get data for if space is pushed or not
    socket.on('spaceData', function(_spaceData) {
        // if space has been pushed set falling speed to 8
        if (_spaceData.pushed == 1) {
            speedFunction(socket, 8);
        }
        // else fall back to speed 1
        else {
            speedFunction(socket, 1);
        }
    });
});

function speedFunction(socket, speed) {
    speedTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        socket.emit('fallingSpeed', {'fallingSpeed': speed});
    }, 1000/60); // send data every frame.
}
```

I have tried using setInterval(...){...} but this only creates loops which we all know is not the greatest when multiple users are connected. This was my code using setInterval(...){...}.

```
// use socket.io
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var speedTimer;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('fallingSpeed', {'fallingSpeed': 1});

    // get data for if space is pushed or not
    socket.on('spaceData', function(_spaceData) {
        // if space has been pushed set falling speed to 8
        if (_spaceData.pushed == 1) {
            clearInterval(speedTimer);
            speedTimer = setInterval(function() {
                socket.emit('fallingSpeed', {'fallingSpeed': 8});
            }, 1000/60); // send data every frame.
        }
        // else fall back to speed 1
        else {
            clearInterval(speedTimer);
            speedTimer = setInterval(function() {
                socket.emit('fallingSpeed', {'fallingSpeed': 1});
            }, 1000/60); // send data every frame.
        }
    });
});
```

So what I need is somehow to check if the value is the correct value when it changes on the clientside.

Comment: You can put your variables/code inside a closure which makes it harder to get to from the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a multiplayer game, you should [never trust the client](http://gafferongames.com/2016/04/25/never-trust-the-client/).

Rethink your architecture. Yes, some information should be given to the client to perform prediction and render the physics, but your server **must** be the **authority** on what's going on in the game.

Comment: Is there an example on how to do validation checks on data properly?

Comment: Run a minimal physics engine and game loop on the server side. You might start with [this article](http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2011/08/creating-realtime-multiplayer-games-using-node-js/) and maybe see if their library is useful to you.